# Regex to filter URL between first and optional second slash

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting, proxy

I am trying to build a Regex to filter a URL.

I need a regex to match the following cases:

`http://proxy/www.test.com` i want the result to be **www.test.com**

`http://proxy/www.test.com/test` i want the result to be **www.test.com**

`http://proxy/test.org/test` i want the result to be **test.org**

`http://proxy/app.local-test:5555/test` i want the result to be **app.local-test:5555**

`http://proxy/local-test:5555/test` i want the result to be **local-test:5555**

I got this regex: `(?<=proxy\/)(.*)(?=\/)` which filters the url quite right, but is depended on a second slash. The second slash is optional, so my regex does not do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace greedy dot matching with a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
(?<=proxy\/)[^\/]+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hI3rC5/1)

The `.*` is "greedy" (meaning it can match as many characters other than a newline as possible), and you tried to restrict the match with the look-ahead. In fact, a negated character class  is safer and more efficient.

The `[^/]` just means *any character but a `/`*. Thus, you can omit the look-ahead altogether.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `(?<=proxy\/)([^\/]+)`

Answer (score 0):

I like to use negative comparatives at the end of sentences

You can try with:

`(?<=proxy\/)([^\s\/]+)`